# How does Kubernetes track which cloud disk is attached to which Pod in a StatefulSet?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I created a StatefulSet on GKE, and it provisioned a bunch of GCE disks that are attached to the pods that belong to that StatefulSet. Suppose I scale the StatefulSet to 0: the constituent pods are destroyed and the disks are released. When I scale back up, the disks are reattached and mounted inside the correct pods.

My questions are:

- How does Kubernetes keep track of which GCE disk to reconnect to which StatefulSet pod?
- Suppose I want to restore a StatefulSet Pod's PV from a snapshot. How can I get Kubernetes to use the disk that was created from the snapshot, instead of old disk?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you scale the StatefulSet to 0 replicas, the pods get destroyed but the persistent volumes and persistent volume claims are kept. The association with the GCE disk is written inside the PersistentVolume object. When you scale the RS up again, pods are assigned to the correct PV and thus get the same volume from GCE.

In order to change the persistent volume - GCE disk association after a snapshot restore, you need to edit the PV object.

Comment: Thank you. The second part I already figured out: in my case, because I'm on GCE, I was able to edit `spec.gcePersistentDisk.pdName` and replaced it with the name of my restored image. But my first question remains (and this is mostly a matter of curiosity at this point)—how does the StatefulSet controller identify which ordinal needs which PV?

Comment: I think that, by design, the StatefulSet associates PVCs and Pods by name. As you know, pods in a StatefulSet have names which are less random than those generated by a ReplicaSet, such as mypod-0, mypod-1 and so on. I guess that StatefulSet implementation simply maps those pod names with the homologous PVC such as mypod-0 gets associated with mypvc-0 and so on

Comment: Ohhh that’s right the PVCs are ordinaled, too. Yes, that makes sense. Thank you.

Comment: Do you see any problems with the fact that I manually edited the PV to switch out the underlying cloud disk?

Comment: As long as you're sure that the content of the disk is correct, no there is no problem. PVs, in fact, are meant to be manually managed by the sysadmin and the fact that they get automatically created is a GCE feature. You are perfectly allowed to edit them

Comment: Super. Thank you. I just had to learn to do backup restore. Thankfully I had this running: https://github.com/miracle2k/k8s-snapshots/issues/38. In process of Googling about this I discovered https://blog.jetstack.io/blog/volume-snapshotting/. Looks like automatic restores will be a thing in the future.

Comment: Interesting! Thanks for sharing

Answer (score 1):

[Kubernetes 1.12](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2018/09/27/kubernetes-1.12-kubelet-tls-bootstrap-and-azure-virtual-machine-scale-sets-vmss-move-to-general-availability/#additional-notable-feature-updates) start addressing this issue in a more generalized way with **Snapshot / restore** functionality for Kubernetes and [CSI (Container Storage Interface)](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2018/04/10/container-storage-interface-beta/), introduced as an alpha feature.
This provides standardized APIs design (CRDs) and adds PV snapshot/restore support for [CSI volume drivers](https://kubernetes-csi.github.io/docs/).

This is no longer specific to GKE.

See the feature request "[Snapshot / Restore Volume Support for Kubernetes (CRD + External Controller)](https://github.com/kubernetes/features/issues/177)" and its associated [CSI snapshot design](https://github.com/kubernetes/community/pull/2335).

The statefulSet aspect was [not yet fully addressed in this](https://github.com/xing-yang/community/blob/772498694fba68a37f450ed9c0f21e4aedd0e5bf/contributors/design-proposals/storage/csi-snapshot.md#non-goals) at the beta level, but will be in the future:

> The following are non-goals for the current phase, but will be considered at a later phase.
>
> Goal 5: Provide higher-level management, such as backing up and restoring a pod and statefulSet, and creating a consistent group of snapshots.

See [PR for the documentation](https://github.com/kubernetes/website/pull/9948): "**[Volume Snapshot and Restore Volume from Snapshot Support](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#volume-snapshot-and-restore-volume-from-snapshot-support)**"